# Get access to Stripe Portal

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I have set up a Node server to manage subscriptions and now I am trying to add the connection to the Stripe Customer Portal (so that I can outsource to them subscription management after creation).

The instructions says:

Create a button to be clicked by user:

```
<form method="POST" action="/create_customer_portal_session">
    <button type="submit">Manage billing</button>
</form>
```

and then add the endpoint for this:

```
// Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production!
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_yvBluFKhx8Xg1vjZVoulY8NO003U0HnRoA');

var session = await stripe.billingPortal.sessions.create({
  customer: 'cus_IETxeMQvgvY05a',
  return_url: 'https://example.com/account',
});
```

So I took my current server implementation and tried to update it to include this event:

```
/* Get your Stripe publishable key to initialize Stripe.js */
fetch("https://***.com:4343/setup")
  .then(function(result) {
    return result.json();
  })
  .then(function(json) {
    var publicKey = json.publicKey;
    var basicPlanId = json.basicPlan;
    var proPlanId = json.proPlan;

    var stripe = Stripe(publicKey);
    // Setup event handler to create a Checkout Session when button is clicked
    document
      .getElementById("basic-plan-btn")
      .addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
        customerEmail=document.querySelector('[name="username"]').value;
        createCheckoutSession(basicPlanId).then(function(data) {
          // Call Stripe.js method to redirect to the new Checkout page
          stripe
            .redirectToCheckout({
                  sessionId: data.sessionId,
            })
            .then(handleResult);
        });
      });

    // Setup event handler to create a Checkout Session when button is clicked
    document
      .getElementById("pro-plan-btn")
      .addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
        customerEmail=document.querySelector('[name="username"]').value;
        createCheckoutSession(proPlanId,customerEmail).then(function(data) {
          // Call Stripe.js method to redirect to the new Checkout page
          stripe
            .redirectToCheckout({
              sessionId: data.sessionId
            })
            .then(handleResult);
        });
      });
    
    //PART  ADDED TO CALL THE USER PORTAL
    //Setup event handler to create a Portal Sesssion when button is clicked
    document
        .getElementById("portal")
        .addEventListener("click",function(evt){
            var customerId = 'cus_IETxeMQvgvY05a';
            stripe.billingPortal.sessions.create({
                customer: 'cus_IETxeMQvgvY05a',
                return_url: 'https://***.com/account',
            });
        });
    });
```

but when I try to click on the button I get that Stripe.BillinPortal is undefined.

The other two request work smootly: for each I have a function defined like this:

```
var createCheckoutSession = function(planId,customerEmail) {
  return fetch("https://***.com:4343/create-checkout-session", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      planId: planId,
      customerEmail: customerEmail
    })
  }).then(function(result) {
    return result.json();
  });
};
```

and the correspondent handler on the node server is this:

```
app.post("/create-checkout-session", async (req, res) => {
  const domainURL = process.env.DOMAIN;
  const { planId,customerEmail } = req.body;
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    customer_email: customerEmail,
    line_items: [{price: planId, quantity: 1}],
    subscription_data: { 
        //items: [{ plan: planId }]
        trial_period_days: 15
    },
    metadata: {'planId': planId},
    success_url: `${domainURL}/success.html?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
    cancel_url: `${domainURL}/canceled.html` ,
    mode: 'subscription',
  });

  res.send({
    sessionId: session.id
  });
});
```

I am stuck at how to do the same with the Customer Portal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use `stripe.billingPortal.sessions` in your *frontend* code, which won't work. (the code with `//PART  ADDED TO CALL THE USER PORTAL`)

The session should created on your backend server instead. You then return the URL the frontend and can set `window.location` to it for example. It's similar to how you already implemented a backend route to fetch a CheckoutSession, just here you are fetching the `url` field of the Billing Session and all your frontend code needs to do is redirect to it directly.(you don't need to use a Stripe frontend library like you do with `redirectToCheckout`).

Comment: Why isn't there a method similar to redirectToCheckout for the customer portal? If customers can update their payment information, then why isn't there some sort of secure session created the same way as with the checkout?

Comment: Note that `redirectToCheckout` doesn't have to be used anymore either and you can access and redirect to a `url` from the backend. In any case the idea is that *your* backend needs to authenticate the customer and only generate a CustomerPortal link for them if you trust them and that the current browser session is that customer. For example in https://github.com/stripe-samples/developer-office-hours/tree/master/2020-06-29-customer-portal that's based on a RoR session(a HTTP Session cookie), you would tie this into authentication systems in your site.